# writing data into a csv file as float values in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, csv, floating-point

I want to write data into a `.csv` file using python as float values. everytime I try to do it using the writerow function of the csv module it writes into the csv file but in quotes, rendering it as a `string`. I also cannot use `float()` function since the data acquires is in a `list`. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is correct behaviour. From [wiki 'Comma-separated values'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values):

> Standardization
>
> > Any field may be quoted (with double quotes).

EDIT

To avoid quoting u can set `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` in your csv writer. Working example for Python 3.5.2:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    spamwriter.writerow([str(1.1112233), str(1.3355)])
```

egg.csv

```
1.1112233,1.3355
```

Comment: thanks for the response. how can i remove the quotes appearing automatically in csv file?

Comment: I extended my answer. It's good idea to look at:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882024/using-python-csv-writer-without-quotations aswell.

Comment: Thanx for all ur responses but I got over with it by using the np.genfromtxt function, and setting the delimiters and the deletechars