# Quotes around records using csv.writer

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have:

```
   datafile = csv.writer(open(filename, 'a', newline=''))
   result_set = source_mysql_cursor.fetchall()
   print (result_set)
   datafile.writerows(result_set)
```

The csv looks:

```
"item1,item2,item3"
```

Tried everything google provided:(

I am expecting this:

```
item1,item2,item3
```

Comment: What is the SQL query you're running in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using python csv writer without quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882024/using-python-csv-writer-without-quotations)

Comment: @AKX: This is quite complex (business query I cannot share here).

Comment: @MSpruijt: No, the quotes are around the whole record.

Comment: Looks like `result_set` is an iterable of strings, not anything CSV Writer can recognize as a three-value rows.  What does `print(result_set)` display?

Comment: @NikolajŠ.: [('result1,result2,',), ('result3,result4',)]

Comment: Please add that to the question, and make sure that CSV contents matches `result_set` =)

Comment: @Pythonist You don't need to share the actual query, but right, if your query returns lines that have a single column that has multiple values separated by commas, you'll of course have to split it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say `result_set` looks like

> `[('result1,result2,',), ('result3,result4',)]`

– i.e. each row has a single column with comma-separated values – you'll need to split the single column:

```
datafile.writerows((col.split(",") for (col,) in result_set))
```

Comment: Yes! You saved my life (and the weekend as well :)). Thank you.